# KOMA footnotes and epltxfn.sty

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, linguistics, expex

I am trying to use my own style for footnotes defined with `scrartcl` together with the footnote-specific example labeling (i) for `expex` provided by `epltxfn`. However, whichever of the two footnote definitions is written last seems to overwrite the other completely, as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\deffootnote{2em}{1em}{\thesection.\thefootnotemark.\enskip}
\usepackage{expex,epltxfn}
 
\begin{document}
    \section{A Section}
    Some text and        
    \ex a normal example\xe
    Some more text\footnote{And here \ex an example inside a footnote\xe}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`expex` documentation](https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf), the (very short) code of `epltxfn` is explained in a way that makes it very easy to create a version of it using your own footnote style.
Or you could misappropriate the `addtokomafont` macro to add only the renumbering part of `epltxfn` to every footnote, like so:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\deffootnote{2em}{1em}{\thesection.\thefootnotemark.\enskip}
\usepackage{expex}

\newcommand{\evryftnt}{\keepexcntlocal\excnt=1%
    \lingset{exskip=1ex,exnotype=roman,sampleexno=,%
    labeltype=alpha,labelanchor=numright,numoffset=2em,labeloffset=.5em,textoffset=.5em}}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\evryftnt}

\begin{document}
    \section{A Section}
    Some text and
    \ex a normal example\xe
    Some more text\footnote{And here \ex an example inside a footnote\xe}
\end{document}
```

with an added `numoffset` to match the indent of your footnotes.